# Need a regular expression in python to separate the signal definitions

Tags: python, regex

The string which contains the signal definitons is of the form,

> signal_a=(3=box1:soc1.sig_a1|box1:soc1.sig_a0;2=box2:band_x1;1=xbox:abis|xbox1:bbs.seg_b;0=trip:skip);signal_b=super:mario|repp:ver;signal_c=semi:six_sig;signal_d=(1=last:end|start:twist;0=demo:test)

I want to separate signal definition and put them in a list. Something like below,

```
signalDefList = [
    'signal_a=(3=box1:soc1.sig_a1|box1:soc1.sig_a0;2=box2:band_x1;1=xbox:abis|xbox1:bbs.seg_b;0=trip:skip)',
    'signal_b=super:mario|repp:ver',
    'signal_c=semi:six_sig',
    'signal_d=(1=last:end|start:twist;0=demo:test)'
]
```

Can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

### Code

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/bPjlMh/1)

```
;(?=signal)
```

Replacement: `\n`

#### Usage

[See code in use here](https://ideone.com/9Wl9pV)

```
import re

r = r";(?=signal)"
s = "signal_a=(3=box1:soc1.sig_a1|box1:soc1.sig_a0;2=box2:band_x1;1=xbox:abis|xbox1:bbs.seg_b;0=trip:skip);signal_b=super:mario|repp:ver;signal_c=semi:six_sig;signal_d=(1=last:end|start:twist;0=demo:test)"
print re.split(r,s)
```

Output:

```
['signal_a=(3=box1:soc1.sig_a1|box1:soc1.sig_a0;2=box2:band_x1;1=xbox:abis|xbox1:bbs.seg_b;0=trip:skip)', 'signal_b=super:mario|repp:ver', 'signal_c=semi:six_sig', 'signal_d=(1=last:end|start:twist;0=demo:test)']
```

---

### Results

#### Input

> signal_a=(3=box1:soc1.sig_a1|box1:soc1.sig_a0;2=box2:band_x1;1=xbox:abis|xbox1:bbs.seg_b;0=trip:skip);signal_b=super:mario|repp:ver;signal_c=semi:six_sig;signal_d=(1=last:end|start:twist;0=demo:test)

#### Output

```
signal_a=(3=box1:soc1.sig_a1|box1:soc1.sig_a0;2=box2:band_x1;1=xbox:abis|xbox1:bbs.seg_b;0=trip:skip)
signal_b=super:mario|repp:ver
signal_c=semi:six_sig
signal_d=(1=last:end|start:twist;0=demo:test)
```

---

### Explanation

- `;` Match the semicolon character `;` literally
- `(?=signal)` Positive lookahead ensuring what follows is `signal` literally

Comment: Would help if you could clarify/explain your approach a little.

Comment: @ArthurVigil I did in the **Explanation** section

Comment: Thanks a lot :)
I never used the look ahead feature and now I found it very helpful and it makes spiting strings very simple.

Comment: You're welcome @ChethanKumarN! If it answers your question you should mark it as the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

As it was already answered you should use `;(?=signal)`.

To get desired output put it inside `re.split()` method:

```
import re
signalDefList = re.split(';(?=signal)', data)
signalDefList
#['signal_a=3=box1:soc1.sig_a1|box1:soc1.sig_a0;2=box2:band_x1;1=xbox:abis|xbox1:bbs.seg_b;0=trip:skip)',
# 'signal_b=super:mario|repp:ver',
# 'signal_c=semi:six_sig',
# 'signal_d=(1=last:end|start:twist;0=demo:test)']
```